# Column without last characters with awk and printf

Tags: bash, awk, printf

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

f_status () {
        systemctl list-units | grep $1 | awk '{ printf("SERVICE STATUS:  %-25s \t %s \t %s \t %s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4) }'
}

f_line() {
        echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
}

echo ""
f_line
f_status "cron"
f_status "ssh"
f_line
```

This script gives me such a result:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SERVICE STATUS:  cron.service                    loaded          active          running
SERVICE STATUS:  ssh.service                     loaded          active          running
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and I search how to remove ".service" from 3d column.

I tried with substr($i, 0, -8) and ${1:-8}

Does anyone have any idea how to get rid of 8 characters from the end to make it look like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SERVICE STATUS:  cron                    loaded          active          running
SERVICE STATUS:  ssh                     loaded          active          running
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `systemctl list-units | grep $1` -> `systemctl list-units $1`

Comment: @KamilCuk, good point, but not really equivalent

Comment: `sed 's/\.service//'`?

Comment: `awk '{sub(".service","")}1'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never need grep when you're using awk since `grep 'foo' file | awk '{print 7}'` can be written as just `awk '/foo/{print 7}' file`.

Rather than counting characters, just remove everything starting from the last `.`:

```
systemctl list-units |
awk -v tgt="$1" '
    {
        svc = $1
        sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",svc)
    }
    svc == tgt {
        printf "SERVICE STATUS:  %-25s \t %s \t %s \t %s\n",svc,$2,$3,$4
    }
'
```

I also tightened up your comparison to avoid false matches if called with a service name that's a subset of some other service name or contains regexp metachars like `.`.

Comment: Thank You for mega fast answer. Thanks also for the advice on "grep" and "awk" - I'll keep that in mind. I spent 4 hours on this task and I had no idea how to solve it.

Comment: I chose Your solution and followed your recommendations for post-response behavior. Thank you again and best regards!

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute end position based on string length, consider following simple example, let `file.txt` content be

```
cron.service
ssh.service
```

then

```
awk '{print substr($1,1,length($1)-8)}' file.txt
```

output

```
cron
ssh
```

Explanation: arguments for [`substr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) are string, start position, end position, `length` return number of characters in string.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Thank You for explanation. I tried this way before: substr($1, length, -8), but I didn't think that I should specify a variable that should count the number of characters.

Comment: @gacek `length` when used without `()` is just variable holding number of characters in whole line (`$0`) rather than particular field, for example if you would have file with single lines: `123 456` then `{print length}` gives `7`, as it has 6 digits and space.

Comment: regarding `length when used without () is just variable` - no, it's still a function call, it's just shorthand for `length($0)`. If it was a variable then, among other things, you could assign a value to it but you can't.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `gsub` funtion in awk,like the following:

```sh
 systemctl list-units | grep 'cron' | awk '{gsub(".service","",$1); printf("SERVICE STATUS:  %-25s \t %s \t %s \t %s\n",$1, $2 ,$3,$4) }'
SERVICE STATUS:  crond                       loaded      active      running
```

Comment: 1) `gsub()` is for making multiple substitutions while you only want to do 1 so you should be using `sub()` instead, 2) the first argument for any of the `*sub()` functions is a regexp, not a string, so you should be using regexp `/.../`, not string `"..."`, delimiters, 3) you should anchor your regexp with a terminating `$` so you remove the last occurrence on the line, not the first, 4) you need to escape the `.` in a regexp or it'll match any character, not just the `.` you want to match, 5) you dont need `grep` when youre using `awk` since `grep 'cron' | awk '{foo}'` = `awk '/cron/{foo}'`.